# Subtract Date offset from Date

Tags: java, date

When I print the date I can see an offset of -6.00

```
2012-12-31T18:00:00 -0600
```

is there a clean way to add the offset to the date, I can't see anything in `java.util.Date`.

I am printing the date using the following:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
String date = sdf.format(new Date(dateInMilliseconds));
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "add the offset to the date"? And how are you "printing the date"? (And can you use Joda Time?)

Comment: The offset tells you what time zone your date / time is for.  You don't have to add the offset to the date.

Comment: edited post, unfortunately I don't have Joda Time.

Comment: Are you asking to see the date in UTC?

Answer (score 2):

The offset has to do with [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

If you're working with a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), you can get the TimeZone like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

If you have a TimeZone instance, you can get the offset for a given date like this:

```
int offset = tz.getOffset(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask "*can I add the offset?*"

If you want to standardize your dates, you could just use UTC time.

You could do this with a SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

The output right now:

```
  2013-06-25T19:09:10
```